# jQuery many same input get same result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My question is quite simple I think : I'm using jQuery Mobile.
And I have on 3 pages exactly the same form for the same purpose.
I would like when I input something on any of theme it apply's on the others so when the user changes pages he will see his inputs.

I've been searching on the web all I could find is input from 1 specif form to apply to the other but not from any of theme to all.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need some way to save the information in between pages, whether it is in the URL (`...com/foo?selection=bar`), browser storage (cookies, localStorage), or on a server with that user's preferences. Unless this is a single page app, all JavaScript memory is wiped away when the user goes to a new page, so you'll need some other way for the data to persist. It seems like a browser storage technique will work well for what you're doing, but do know that they are not permanent, and you may need to inform your user that you're using cookies depending on where your user lives (EU).

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on what exactly you'd like to achieve.

If you want values from the form on page1 to appear on page1...pageN after you reload the page, you can use `localStorage`. The idea is to save all input values to variables, array or object when you need them to be saved

```
localStorage.setItem("formValues", formValuesObject)
```

And to check for that item on pageload.

```
localStorage.getItem("formValues")
```

Set values to the form, if they already exist.

But this solution will not work if pageI is already opened in new tab. To refresh the form values in all tabs if they are modified from any of them you will need to check for edit periodically. You can use `setInterval(refreshFormValues, delay)` for this purpose.

If you want those values to remain the same even after browser is closed, you need server-side solution, use cookies for that.

Comment: I tryed it also but as you said it's only on refresh and jQuery mobile all the pages are loaded at the same time so it doesn't work =/

I was thinking about something with input name where the input is automatically applied to the other but as far as I went it work from one specific input but not from any of theme

Comment: Then try server-side solution. Send form data with `ajax`, save them on server in session storage. On each page make periodical `ajax` calls to server to get the newest values.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :

There is a bit of jQuery Mobile and JavaScript

So the thing is to store the input data in SessionStorage and on page change get back the data on the input of the page you are.

On page 1 #instant_mesure

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" placeholder="Date de l'événement" id="instant_mesuredateevent" onchange="sessionStorage.dateevent=this.value">
```

On page 2 #instant_inspiration

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" placeholder="Date de l'événement" id="instant_inspirationdateevent" onchange="sessionStorage.dateevent=this.value">
```

And the JS

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#instant_mesure', function (e, data) {
  if('dateevent' in sessionStorage) {
    document.getElementById('instant_mesuredateevent').value = sessionStorage.getItem('dateevent');
  }
});
$(document).on('pageshow', '#instant_inspiration', function (e, data) {
  if('dateevent' in sessionStorage) {
    document.getElementById('instant_inspirationdateevent').value = sessionStorage.getItem('dateevent');
  }
});
```

Thanks for you're time and help =)